# Using micronaut on CloudRun fully managed

Tags: java, micronaut, google-cloud-run

I tried to run micronaut framework on Cloud Run for testing clod start performance.

When I deploy in command line, I have this issue:

```
Deploying...
  Creating Revision... Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information....failed
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.
```

However, I tested several dockerfile configuration, and I think that my last one is good for passing the EnvVar port to the expected Micronaut EnvVar:

```
FROM gradle:jdk11-slim as builder
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
RUN gradle build

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11-openj9:jdk-11.0.1.13-alpine-slim
COPY --from=builder /home/gradle/src/build/libs/micronaut-jib-cr*.jar micronaut-jib-cr.jar
ENV MICRONAUT_SERVER_PORT=${PORT}
EXPOSE ${PORT}
CMD java  -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -noverify ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar micronaut-jib-cr.jar
```

So, I went deeped in the Cloud Run logs, and I saw an another cause of this problem

```
D  Container Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported syscall setsockopt(0x8,0x1,0xc,0x2ae1273fc05c,0x4,0x32) 
D  Container Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported syscall setsockopt(0x8,0x6,0x6,0x2ae1273fc03c,0x4,0x3a) 
A  Error: Could not find or load main class micronaut.jib.cr.Application 
A  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: micronaut.jib.cr.Application 
D  Container Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported syscall semctl(0x1,0x0,0x2,0x2ae12753ef50,0x2,0x2ae12753ef50) 
D  Container Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported syscall semctl(0x1,0x0,0x2,0x2ae12753ef50,0x2,0x2ae12753ef50) 
D  Container Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported syscall semctl(0x1,0x0,0x2,0x2ae12753f440,0x2,0x2ae12753f440) 
D  Container Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported syscall semctl(0x1,0x0,0x2,0x2ae12753f440,0x2,0x2ae12753f440) 
D  Container Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported syscall semctl(0x1,0x0,0x2,0x2ae12753f440,0x2,0x2ae12753f440) 
D  Container Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported syscall semctl(0x1,0x0,0x2,0x2ae12753f440,0x2,0x2ae12753f440)
```

Is it a real wrong port usage ? In this case, can you help me with my dockerfile ?

If not, is it a known Cloud Run limitation ?

There is a work-around on micronaut to solve this syscall limitation ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You have asked 4 questions and not all of them make sense to me.  Are you able to successfully build and deploy the app at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-gcp/tree/master/examples/hello-world-cloud-run?

Comment: Your container is not working: `Error: Could not find or load main class micronaut.jib.cr.Application`. Get your container to work on your desktop first. Next your container is making unsupported gVisor syscalls: https://gvisor.dev/docs/user_guide/compatibility/amd64/ - somtimes this is harmless, other times fatal.

Comment: I ran "docker build" on the Dockerfile mentioned, but got the error of: "Step 6/9 : COPY --from=builder /home/gradle/src/build/libs/micronaut-jib-cr*.jar micronaut-jib-cr.jar                         
COPY failed: no source files were specified". Is it expected?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a port issue. It looks like you hit a limitation of [gvisor](https://github.com/google/gvisor), which is the sandbox used by Cloud Run. Your container is trying to make a syscall that the sandbox does not (yet) support, which is causing the container to crash during start-up.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, John Hanley was right. My gradle build didn't reference the correct main class... I shame of this evident error. But I used Visual Studio Code for the first time (because it seems trendy!), and the package refactor is not as efficient as IntelliJ one ! (Or I haven't the right plugin!)

Thanks for your help, now it work perfectly (and more again with GraalVM packaging!)